# How can I show a highstock graph with a linear timeline

Tags: charts, highcharts

I have generated a graph inside highstock (see example - http://jsfiddle.net/szFQa/), 
however, by default, it groups data that is chronologically close together, and stops the timeline from showing time in a linear form.

I've tried using the following options, there seems to be no change though.

```
        plotOptions : {
            series : {
                dataGrouping : {
                    enabled : false
                },
            }
        },
```

What options need to be set to stop the grouping and show the timeline as linear?

Answer (score 0):

In case when you disable dataGrouping like this http://jsfiddle.net/szFQa/1/ then points are not grouped, because in your data you have 16 points and on the chart is also 16 points.

```
    plotOptions: {
        series: {
            dataGrouping:{
                enabled:false
            },
            marker: {
                enabled: true
            }
        }
    },
```